# Create a ruby object from a supertype object

Tags: ruby, factory, subtype

I am using the Selenium Webdriver libraries in Ruby. A typical piece of code looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox 
# driver is an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Driver

url = 'http://www.google.com/'
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
driver.get(url)
wait.until { driver.title.start_with? "Google" }
```

I would like to create a subclass of `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver` called `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver::MyClass` that will contain some new methods and instance variables.

As the above code illustrates, the way that instances of `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver` are created is with `Selenium::WebDriver.for`.

Without wholesale copying of code, how can I create a version of `Selenium::WebDriver.for` that does the same thing as `Selenium::WebDriver.for` but creates instances of `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver::MyClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just override the `Selenium::WebDriver.for` ? let me show you that my an example

```
# selenium code
module Selenium
  class WebDriver
    def self.for
      puts "creating oldclass"
    end
  end
end

# your code
class Selenium::WebDriver
  def self.for
    puts "creating myclass"
  end
end

Selenium::WebDriver.for
```

output:

```
creating myclass
```

Safe alternative is to derive class from `Selenium::WebDriver` and use that in your code, or to the extreme you can just open Driver class and add your behavior to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb#26). `Selenium::WebDriver.for` simply delegate the method call to `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for`.

If you don't have listener attached, you can simple create your own bridge `MyClass::Bridge.new` and then pass that to `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.new`.

If you insist override the `for` method, here is some code snippet that might help.

```rb
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class Driver
      class << self
        alias_method :old_for, :for
        def for(browser, opts = {})
          if browser == :myclass
            # create your MyClass::Bridge instance and pass that to new()
          else
            old_for(browser, opts)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to define some extra methods on your driver, you do not need to override WebDriver.for.

The following worked well for me:

First, in file customdriver.rb

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
class CustomDriver < Selenium::WebDriver::Driver 
  #a custom method..
  def click_on (_id)
    element = find_element :id => _id
    element.click
  end 
  #add other custom methods here
  #....
end
```

Then, in file main.rb

```
require-relative 'customdriver'
driver = CustomDriver.for :chrome
driver.click_on("buttonID")
```

Regards,